# Open MPI: simple manager/workers pattern in C

Tags: c, mpi

**I'm currently modifying a research project** (massive test and benchmark of diverse conjectures to try and eventually solve the [SSW conjecture](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/op/monochromatoc_reachability_in_arc_colored_digraphs)) **so that it can run on a big HPC architecture**, which does not handle most of the 'classic' multi-process/multi-thread methods (like fork-based in C, python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) module, or multi-threading libraries).

So **I have to go for an [OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/) based implementation**.

**I need advice on the manager/worker pattern, and on the 'good and legit' way to use open MPI, good practices included.** I'm also taking advices on coding style and the likes, but it's not the main issue here (academic lab coding style :-) ).

The rest of the code (the actual jobs to perform) are working fine, benchmarked, tested, and ... confidential. So **here is a toy case, where a job will consist in printing an integer, sleeping for a short time span, and returning no piece of information to the manager**. Error managing for workers is also handled at worker level, so we don't need to really care about it here.

The principle is the following: **I have a 'manager' which sends jobs to perform to a number of workers** (a few thousands in my case). **Each worker is totally independent**, and does not need to return any information to its manager. Workers errors are handled in the workers code.

Here is my toy program:

```
/* file: test_mpi.c */

#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define KEEP_WORKING 0
#define NO_MORE_JOBS 1
#define READY_TO_WORK 2
#define WORKER_NOT_AVAILABLE -1
#define MANAGER_RANK 0
#define NB_JOBS 8


int get_rank_from_ready_worker() {
    MPI_Status status;
    int worker_useless_msg;
    MPI_Recv(&worker_useless_msg,
             1,
             MPI_INT,
             MPI_ANY_SOURCE,
             MPI_ANY_TAG,
             MPI_COMM_WORLD,
             &status);

    if (status.MPI_TAG == READY_TO_WORK) {
        return status.MPI_SOURCE;
    } else {
        return WORKER_NOT_AVAILABLE;
    }
}


void send_job_to_worker(int job, int worker_rank) {
    MPI_Send(&job,
             1,
             MPI_INT,
             worker_rank,
             KEEP_WORKING,
             MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}


void signal_to_manager_that_ready() {
    int empty_msg = 0;
    MPI_Send(&empty_msg,
             1,
             MPI_INT,
             MANAGER_RANK,
             READY_TO_WORK,
             MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}


void do_job(int job, int my_rank) {
    unsigned int sleep_time = 1 + ((rand() + job) % 4);
    sleep(sleep_time);
    printf("[%d] performed job %d\n",
           my_rank, job);
}


bool receive_job_from_manager(int my_rank) {
    int job;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Recv(&job,
             1,
             MPI_INT,
             MANAGER_RANK,
             MPI_ANY_TAG,
             MPI_COMM_WORLD,
             &status);

    if (status.MPI_TAG == KEEP_WORKING) { /* received a job to perform */
        do_job(job, my_rank);
        /* tell manager that it's ready to perform a new job */
        signal_to_manager_that_ready();
        return true;

    } else if (status.MPI_TAG == NO_MORE_JOBS) { /* work is over ! */
        return false;
    } else { /* this should not happen */
        return false;
    }
}

void terminate_worker(int worker_rank) {
    int empty_job = 0;
    MPI_Send(&empty_job,
             1,
             MPI_INT,
             worker_rank,
             NO_MORE_JOBS,
             MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    /* init MPI environment */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    /* Find out rank, size */
    int world_rank, world_size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    /* Check that we have at least one manager & one worker */
    if (world_size < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "World size must be greater than 1 for %s\n", argv[0]);
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
    }

    if (world_rank == MANAGER_RANK) { /* manager part */
        /* create 'jobs'*/
        int jobs[NB_JOBS];
        for (int i = 0; i < NB_JOBS; i++) {
            jobs[i] = i;
        }

        int job_to_send = 0, worker_rank;
        do { /* manager main loop: sending jobs to ready workers */
            worker_rank = get_rank_from_ready_worker();
            if (worker_rank != WORKER_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
                send_job_to_worker(jobs[job_to_send], worker_rank);
                job_to_send ++;
            }
        } while (job_to_send < NB_JOBS);

        /* All jobs done -> terminating workers */
        for (int nb_terminated = 0; nb_terminated < world_size-1; nb_terminated++) {
            terminate_worker(get_rank_from_ready_worker());
        }

    } else { /* worker part */
        /* signal to manager that it's ready to work */
        signal_to_manager_that_ready();

        /* start working loop */
        bool keep_working;
        do {
            keep_working = receive_job_from_manager(world_rank);
        } while (keep_working);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

To compile and run (on unix):

```
mpicc test_mpi.c -o test_mpi -Wall -Wextra
mpirun -n 4 ./test_mpi
```

Note that to compile and run this code, Open MPI needs to be installed on the machine.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

Small review

**Potential bug**

`rand() + job` can overflow leading to *undefined behavior*.  Possible then that `1 + ((rand() + job) % 4)` is a negative number and code sleeps for a *long* time.

e.g. `rand() + job` --> `INT_MAX + 2` --> `-INT_MAX` and `(-INT_MAX) % 4` --> -3.  `-3 + 1` --> `unsigned int sleep_time` is `UINT_MAX -1`.  Sleep maybe 136 year, longer than old [Rip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_Van_Winkle).

Avoid signed integer overflow.  Consider unsigned math.

```
// unsigned int sleep_time = 1 + ((rand() + job) % 4);
unsigned int sleep_time = 1 + ((0u + rand() + job) % 4);
sleep(sleep_time);
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting it :-) Even if it is not going to be part of the code that will run on the big  machines, I always like to see how easy it is to create potentially catastrophic bugs in C (and this one would go undetected for a long long time, with such a low probability of being triggered). I'd give a second +1 for the reference to rip but unfortunately I can't.